# Can't call a method from another class using object

Tags: objective-c, class, object, ios7, methods

I am trying to call a method from another class using a object. There comes no warnings or errors, but the call is not been made. Execution is not been transferred to the method specified.

```
@interface ePub : NSObject 
- (void) paginateChapters;

@implementation ePub 

- (void) paginateChapters;
{
     for (int i=0; i<chapterLinks.count; i++)
     {
        [self splitAttributedStringToPages:[chapterFiles objectAtIndex:i] withChapter:[chaptersAsAttributedStringArray objectAtIndex:i]];
     }
}
```

Then i tried to call using it's object

```
@interface ePubRootViewController : UIViewController 
{
  ePub *loadedEpub;
}

@implementation ePubRootViewController 
-(void) viewDidLoad()
{
   loadedEpub = [[ePub alloc]init];
}

-(void)releaseData
{
    loadedEpub=nil;
}

 -(void)changeFontSize:(id)sender
{
          [self releaseData];
          [loadedEpub paginateChapters];
}
```

Comment: This code should run the NSLog. What else are you doing? Post the rest of your code.

Comment: @CrimsonChris but its not working . I set breakpoints & execution didn't move to the method at all

Comment: Then there is something wrong with the code you are NOT sharing.

Comment: @CrimsonChris what else is needed ?? May i know

Comment: I tried the same code, its working fine for me. The log inside getProperties is printing in the console. Can you try to compile properly.

Comment: Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code you aren't willing to share. Your problem is likely trivial. Go read some beginner objective-c tutorials.

Comment: Your real code is very different from the sample code you originally posted.

Comment: before calling `[loadedEpub paginateChapters];` alloc/initiate the `ePub ` Object.

Comment: The initialization has been done in viewDidLoad ()

Comment: ok thanks alot !!! I have initialized it in viewDidLoad(). But it is been made Nil in another method before the changeFontSize() method has been called. I didn't check it

Comment: Now do you see the importance of posting ALL of your code? If you leave stuff out we can't give you good answers!

Comment: Update your question with the bad code!

Answer (score 2):

Your loadedEPub object is nil when you call the method on it. You must initialize your object before it will respond to method calls.

Comment: ok thanks alot !!! I have initialized it in viewDidLoad(). But it is been made Nil in another method before the changeFontSize() method has been called. I didn't check it